# Como são feita as atualizações do Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Olá, estou pesquisando assuntos relacionados à Wordpress, e procurei algo que fiquei encabulado. Como são feitas as atualizações do wordpress sendo que ele fica instalado no nosso servidor. Ou seja, eu baixo o wordpress, subo no meu dominio, instalo tudo certinho, e as vezes vejo que tem atualizações disponiveis. Como pode isso? Qual arquivo dentro do wordpress faz esse serviço?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O sistema de atualizações do WordPress funciona localmente usando o mesmo mecanismo usado para fazer agendamento de posts e outras tarefas no site, chamado `wp-cron`.

[`Cron`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crontab) é o nome do agendador de tarefas embutido em sistemas Unix, e o `wp-cron` é uma "adaptação" dessa mesma funcionalidade pra rodar em sistemas que não estão permanentemente em execução, como um site em PHP.

O PHP só é executado quando o servidor recebe uma requisição, ou seja, no caso do WordPress, quando um usuário acessa o site. O que o `wp-cron` faz é checar, a cada acesso, se existe uma tarefa agendada a ser cumprida, e se sim, iniciar essa tarefa. Essa checagem é iniciada com uma action ligada ao `init`, disparada no arquivo `wp-includes/default-filters.php`.

[image: imagem do arquivo default-filters.php com a definição da action init]

Uma das tarefas incluídas por padrão é checar, duas vezes ao dia, se existe um aviso de nova versão do WordPress publicado no site central. Essa checagem é feita na função [`wp_version_check()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_version_check/), que fica no arquivo `wp-includes/update.php`. Essa função faz uma requisição `POST` para `http://api.wordpress.org/core/version-check/1.7/` enviando detalhes do seu sistema, e essa API responde com a versão mais nova disponível para atualização automática (nem todos os sites podem ser atualizados diretamente para as versões mais novas, por isso ele confere as versões do seu PHP, mySQL, etc, e então ele faz a checagem pra saber qual a versão certa a te oferecer.

Feita essa checagem, o WordPress guarda essa informação em um `transient` chamado `update_core`.

A partir daí, a cada vez que você acessa o `wp-admin` ele confere se a versão guardada no `transient` é superior à atual e, se você tiver os updates automáticos habilitados, já dispara a atualização. Se não, te mostra a mensagem pedindo para atualizar.

Comment: Caraca, agradeço pela ajuda brother.

Comment: Valeu, @VictorHermes. Se a resposta resolveu sua dúvida, marque ali como aceito pra ficar ajudar quem tiver outras dúvidas semelhantes depois.

Answer (score 0):

Geralmente as actualizações de de segurança são feitas de forma automáticas isto é sempre que tiveres conectado a uma Internet , porem isso acontece a traveis de uma conexão directa com o servidor da wordpress que ela possui.

Answer (score -1):

Primeiro de tudo convém ter sempre um backup do seu wordpress. 
Algumas atualizações de segurança são automáticas e o Wordpress faz automaticamente.

O Wordpress tem ligação ao servidor da wordpress, e mostra essas atualizações disponiveis sempre que tem uma ligação a internet.

O codigo de atualizações esta incorporado na seguinte pagina

> wp-admin/options.php